# Interactive Beamer presentation with Clicks and Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, presentations, interaction

I watched a nice presentation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKj6SFIP3w) about atrial fibrillation with interactive features. 
I would like to have similar features too.

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Normal Conduction System}
\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{image.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

where picture

[image]

Clicking right-atrium gives

[image]

Clicking left-atrium gives

[image]

You can click any part of those parts in any order and it gives arrow there. 
I do not know if Beamer is sufficient for this. 
Probably, some combination with Tikz?

**How can you have such an interactive model for a picture in LaTeX?**

Answer (score 3):

You can overlay invisible hyperlinks over the image, they are rectangular but you can tile the image as finely as needed.  Here I use four tiles and clicking on each of the areas of the heart takes you to the relevant page. (One image appears to have been over-written by mistake, ignore that:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{h1}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-120,120){\hyperref[h-ra]{\makebox(40,70){}}}
\put(-75,130){\hyperref[h-la]{\makebox(50,60){}}}
\put(-120,40){\hyperref[h-rv]{\makebox(30,80){}}}
\put(-80,40){\hyperref[h-lv]{\makebox(50,80){}}}
\end{picture}%

\clearpage
\section*{Right atrium\label{h-ra}}
\includegraphics{h-ra}
\clearpage
\section*{Left atrium\label{h-la}}
\includegraphics{h-la}
\clearpage
\section*{Right ventricle\label{h-rv}}
\includegraphics{h-ra}
\clearpage
\section*{Left-ventrical\label{h-lv}}
\includegraphics{h-lv}

\end{document}
```

while positioning the boxes use `\framebox` instead of `\makebox` then you can see the tiles:

[image]

Comment: Any possibility to make all parts of the picture covered by small squares? So you could then click anywhere in the picture because there are so many parts to click. When they are dense enough, atria can be clicked successfully. This procedure is also much more extensible for all pictures.

Comment: @Masi yes that is exactly what I meant by "tile as finely as needed"

Comment: Any command to tile everything 5x5px areas?

Comment: @Masi not really. You can make the tiles with loops (see `multido` picture mode command in any latex tutorial) but I don't see that would help as you have to specify the target of each tile separately anyway.

Comment: To have such a general layer for everything with pictures could be useful.