# Beamer - Unhide Content at click

Tags: beamer, interaction

I am using Beamer LaTeX for a presenation. On one slide I want to interact with the audience and I want to unhide the text (A,B,C,D,E in the MWE) in the order in which the audience mentions these texts (i.e. if they first mention C, then D, then A, I want to click on C to make it appear, then on D so that C and D are visible and then on A so that A,C,D are visible).

I could use a construction as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244123/interactive-beamer-presentation-with-clicks-and-arrows), but I would need an extra slide for any of the possible combinations. Is there any easier method?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79832/change-on-click-in-beamer (not a duplicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `ocgx` package mentioned in the link posted in Andrew's comment I managed to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Questions}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul01}{ocg01}{0}\actionsocg{ocg01}{}{}{A}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul02}{ocg02}{0}\actionsocg{ocg02}{}{}{B}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul03}{ocg03}{0}\actionsocg{ocg03}{}{}{C}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul04}{ocg04}{0}\actionsocg{ocg04}{}{}{D}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul05}{ocg05}{0}\actionsocg{ocg05}{}{}{E}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{Bul06}{ocg06}{0}\actionsocg{ocg06}{}{}{...}\end{ocg}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is hard to find the spot where to click.

Answer (score 5):

This is very cheap, but at the same time very *interactive*.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Questions}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A 
                    \pdfsquarecomment
                        [height=.8cm,width=5cm,voffset=-.2cm,hoffset=-.4cm]
                        {use mouse to move this}
                \item B
                \item C
                \item D
                \item E
                \item ...
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This idea is to build an annotation that covers the contents. When the audience mentions it, use your mouse to move the annotation away. (Or simply press <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete it)

[image]

## Advantage

Since only annotation involves, this is supported by more PDF readers. (In contrast, PDF readers from the unix world does not like javascript and a bunch of useful PDF features. This includes Preview on macOS.)

## Bonus

This is called [Tangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangram).

Have fun!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={300 100 350 150 300 200}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={150 60 250 60 200 10}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={10 50 60 50 60 100}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={10 210 35 235 60 210 35 185}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={150 200 175 225 175 275 150 250}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={300 20 350 20 325 45}]{}
        \pdflinecomment[type=polygon,line={260 190 285 215 285 165}]{}
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
            \draw(current page.center)+(-50bp,-50bp)rectangle+(50bp,50bp);
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clever approach!

Comment: thanks, that looks really great. I managed to get another solution using the `ocgx` package mentioned in Andrew's comment, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This makes the item bullets (triangles, actually) clickable in order to show/hide the following text, using OCGs:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Questions}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg01}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul01}{ocg01}{0}A\end{ocg}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg02}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul02}{ocg02}{0}B\end{ocg}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg03}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul03}{ocg03}{0}C\end{ocg}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg04}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul04}{ocg04}{0}D\end{ocg}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg05}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul05}{ocg05}{0}E\end{ocg}
  \item[\switchocg{ocg06}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}]\mbox{}\begin{ocg}{Bul06}{ocg06}{0}\dots\end{ocg}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```